# How to specify makefile dependencies when source and object suffixes are the same?

Tags: makefile, ibm-midrange

I'm using GNU Make 4.0 to compile objects on an IBM i.  Most items are ok and conflict-free (`.c` compiles to a `.module`, `.pf` compiles to a `.file`), but a couple types of items use the same filename suffix for both source and object.  For example, commands end in `.cmd` for the source code and also for the compiled command object.  This results in a makefile definition like this:

```
C_CODE1.MODULE: C_CODE1.C    # This is ok -- no conflict
COMMAND1.CMD: COMMAND1.CMD   # Error! Make thinks it's a circular dependency.
```

What can be done to tell Make that the `.cmd` item on the left and the one on the right are actually two different items?  The object suffixes are fixed by the operating system and cannot be changed.  The source code suffixes could be changed, but then they wouldn't appear correctly in our code editors without customization.  The source code does exist in a separate directory from the objects, but paths aren't really specified in the makefile, other than when setting up VPATH.

Comment: Are your sources stream files, or are they 'native' source files ie /QSYS.LIB/SMEEPLIB.LIB/QCMDSRC.FILE/COMMAND1.MBR ?  This is interesting to know because traditional developers will use tooling on native source files that pretty much wants the source member type to match a pre-determined list.  Like CMD, PF, RPGLE, etc.  If your sources are in the IFS (stream files) then you may be able to change the file extension from .cmd to something like .cmdsrc because traditional tooling doesn't look at the file extension.  The bigger question: do you need to coordinate with other developers?

Comment: If the only difference between the target and prerequisite is the pathname, then you'll have to put the pathname into the makefile at least for these rules.

Comment: @BuckCalabro The sources are stream files, and use the file extensions that RDi expects (.RPGLE, .CLLE, etc.).  I at one point did try naming command source `.CMDSRC`, but RDi (or LPEX?) didn't know what to make of it.  RDi can likely be customized to understand `.CMDSRC`, but I was trying to keep things as vanilla as possible so new developers can just jump in and start coding, without a lot of special setup. There will be several people working on this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the source, even if you are using traditional source files, it's not necessary to use the standard source member type. You could use say CMDSRC for the source member type of your command source.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm aware that technically any file extension can be used (our code is in the IFS), but I'm having trouble getting RDi to recognize the newly-named file.  In the Remote Systems Explorer, the source file does show up with the pencil icon, but it opens in the editor as just a plain text file with no special parsing.  General > Editors > File Associations has a `*.cmdsrc` entry, as do General > Content Types and LPEX Editor > Parsers > Parser Associations.  Regardless, it sounds like the way to solve my problem is to change the source file extensions for these troublesome file types.

Comment: I was able to get RDi configured correctly by adjusting some preferences. From General → Editors → File Associations, defined `*.cmdsrc` to be identical to `*.cmd`.  From General → LPEX Editor → Parsers → Parser Associations, defined `CMDSRC` and `cmdsrc` to be the same as `CMD` and `cmd`. I also defined `*.cmdsrc` to General → Content Types → Text → Enterprise Source Types → Command definition, but not sure if that was required. After these changes, RDi stubbornly didn't work correctly until I right clicked on a .CMDSRC and selected "Open with Remote Systems LPEX editor" to kick start it.

Answer (score 1):

If the target name does not have to match the prerequisites, I would change the target name to something else, for example `COMMAND1:  COMMAND1.CMD`.

If they have to be matched then I would write like the following to add the extension explicitly in the recipe.

```
COMMAND1 :  COMMAND1.CMD 
     cat $< > ${@}.CMD
```